# How to change string between 2 string in csh?

Tags: csh

I have input file as below and I wish to substitute string between `set xx { \` & `}` as showed in output. How to code in csh?

Input:

```
set a 1
set b 2
set xx { \
a/c/d \
apple/d/e/g \
guava/s/s/g/b/c \
}
set c 3
```

Output:

```
set a 1
set b 2
set xx { \
a/*c*/d* \
apple/d/*e*/g* \
guava/s/s/g/*b*/c* \
}
set c 3
```

Comment: will your "data" be in a file? If not, can it be saved to a temp file? I have a solution for that, but not for `echo "set a 1 ...."`. Good luck.

Comment: Yes. Input is a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat fixer.sed
#!/bin/sed -f
        /set xx {/ , /}/ {
           s@\(/.*\)\([^/]\)\(/[^/]*\)\(  *[\]\)$@\1*\2*\3*\4@
        }
```

`/set xx {/ , /}/` is a range expression, `sed` scans each line, but only performs the `s@...@...@` operations on lines in between the range supplied.

```
$ chmod +x fixer.sed  # only the first time you create file
```

**output**

```
$ ./fixer.sed txt.txt
set a 1
set b 2
set xx { \
a/*c*/d* \
apple/d/*e*/g* \
guava/s/s/g/*b*/c* \
}
set c 3
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `[^/]`?

Comment: any list of characters enclosed like `[aceg]` is called a character class. You can negate the list of characters with the `^` char. So `[^/]` is all chars that are not the `/` char ;-) . (char classes can also take the form on ranges `[a-zA-Z]` and can include numbers and non-alpha chars. Good luck.